# SQL Server pivot and merge column possible?

Tags: sql-server, merge, pivot

I have a table with this data:

```
| RESULT  |     TYPE    |    NAME   | 
+---------+-------------+-----------+
|  101.96 |  Indep Chk  |  Calcium  |  
|  101.96 |  Control    |  Calcium  |  
|  <5.00  |  Meth Blank |  Calcium  |  
|  1      |  Duplicate  |  Calcium  |
```

I am trying to get the following result without success.

Desired output:

```
| [Indep Chk]  |  Control  | Duplicate | [Meth Blank] | Name     |
|  101.96      |   101.96  |   1       |  <5.00       |  Calcium |
```

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to  mention that my table will have different components (name and result ). The "TYPE column" never change for each component. For instance, I could have calcium, zinc, magnesium and so on. Each of this components will always have ("Indep Chk" , Control ,   Duplicate , "Meth Blank") but different Result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do not get this wrong, this is a simple `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(RESULT VARCHAR(100),[TYPE] VARCHAR(100),NAME VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 ('101.96','Indep Chk','Calcium')
,('101.96','Control','Calcium')
,('<5.00','Meth Blank','Calcium')
,('1','Duplicate','Calcium')
,('a','Indep Chk','Other')
,('b','Control','Other')
,('c','Meth Blank','Other')
,('d','Duplicate','Other');

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @Dummy
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(RESULT) FOR [TYPE] IN ([Indep Chk],[Control],Duplicate,[Meth Blank])
) AS p;
```

The result

```
NAME    Indep Chk   Control Duplicate   Meth Blank
Calcium 101.96       101.96 1           <5.00
Other   a            b      d           c
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, it could work but my problem is that I have different components  (name and result ) in my table. The type column never change.

Comment: @Alberto The same query works with multiple NAMEs too. See my update.